# Can I stop unfinished render and still do compositing?

Tags: rendering, interface, compositing-nodes

Just like the title, really. For a normal, uncomposited, render, I can just hit escape; and Blender will stop what it's doing and go back to modeling-ready mode. However, this precludes any compositing.

Suppose I have a model I want in extreme detail, so I set render samples to 100,000,000,000 or something ridiculous and leave it for a weekend. I get back, it's of very high quality, so I stop the render where it is. Afterward, I want a compositor node graph to execute, saving several different versions of the image, some with filters and color adjustments applied.

Escape doesn't permit this. Does anything though?

Comment: Hi :). One ESC press just stops the render. You can still use it for composting. Perhaps add more details why it's not working for you :)

Comment: I'm aware that I can save the image, probably as a multilayer EXR, and then pipe it into a composition tree as an external file, but what I'm specifically looking for is something which will freeze render data as it is, and then automatically pipe it into composition without further interference. This hasn't worked for me with escape.

Comment: Hi :). No need to save the file. Works just like you need. What's your compositor setup? Perhaps it just needs to be refreshed ;)

Comment: Ah... seems you're right, it will work with a half-complete render; however, it doesn't do it automatically (my render window remains uncomposited) and I need to disconnect and reconnect something in the node editor to get it to refresh. Is there an easier way to do that? I don't see any conventional refresh button like I might find in a web browser or file manager.

Comment: Hi :). There's no refresh button afaik. I usually just double tap 'M' to mute/unmute a node. It's not optimal, but works well enough.

Comment: Thank you. If you turn this into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. You have saved me a lot of time—I was figuring that the whole render was lost if I didn't let it run to completion.